# How to use StrictFiltersCompoundOperationType in bot framework using c#

Tags: botframework

How to use **StrictFiltersCompoundOperationType** in bot framework using c#
In which version of Bot framework this option is available?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/metadata-generateanswer-usage#logical-or-using-strictfilterscompoundoperationtype-property

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and, right now, the StrictFiltersCompoundOperationType property is not supported when calling QnA Maker via the Bot Builder SDK.  I have raised an issue in our repo, which will hopefully lead to a fix in the near future.

https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/4346